# Invalid block tag: 'set'

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am trying to set a variable in Jinja template. Just as simple as that. But I got error says : `Invalid block tag: 'set', expected 'endblock'`

Here is my template:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
        <div style="padding-top:100px"></div>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    <i class="mdi-social-person"></i>
                    Reports
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                    {% set index = 'a' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I thought set should be straight forward not this difficult.

Comment: how have you replace Django's default template engine?

Comment: @Gocht no, I am not changing anything related to template engine

Comment: You need follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2) to use jinja with django

Comment: Jinja2 isn't Django's default templating engine. So if you haven't changed anything, this won't work.

Comment: Ah, alright. My fault was I didn't know that set tag is jinja tag, and I didn't know that jinja is not the Django's default templating engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`set` is jinja's tag, but jinja is not Django's default templating engine as @Jharris and @Gocht mentioned in the comment. So, I need to install jinja first to use `set` tag.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `Django template system` (the default templating engine), you can use `with`.

```
{% with index='a' %}
{% endwith %}
```

Note that you need the closing tag, which will give you the scope of your variable. (Also note that you can't have a whitespace between the variable name, the `=` sign, and the value. Because why would anything python-related be flexible. :-/ )

You can read more about the engine [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/) and about the valid tags [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/).

Answer (score -3):

You should use `{% endblock %}` instead of `{% endblock content %}`

Comment: This is not correct, you can have optional naming to the `endblock` in template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance